# Swift-Watch: How to detect user scrolled to last row in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacetable

I need to detect user scrolled to last row in `Watch` app.

Code for `WKInterfaceTable`

```
func loadTableData() {


    notificationTblView.setNumberOfRows(notifications.count, withRowType: "NotificationCellID")
    var index = 0

    while index < notifications.count {
        let row = notificationTblView.rowController(at: index) as! TableRowController

        let dictofObject = notifications[index]
        row.notificationTitleLbl.setText(dictofObject["title"])
        row.notificationDateLbl.setText(dictofObject["time"])
        index = index + 1
   }
}
```

In iPhone application, same concept did. Detected user's last row. Code is below.

This for `UITableView`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == (self.notifications.count - 1)
    {
        //print("\n\ncame to last row")
        self.view.showActivityIndicator(activityTag: 1000)
        self.fetchNotificationData(true)
    }
}
```

Can you guide me for this?

Comment: I take it you want to use that to load the next batch of data?  I had a similar problem with one of my WatchKit apps, and ended up putting a button at the end of the table to load the next batch.  I'd be interested to know if there is a better way, but I cannot see any method on WKInterfaceTable to do so.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. You save my day. But., really much better answer need for this. As of now., I will follow button action.